# How to get previously clicked buttons checked from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, logic

I am fetching an array of objects into my react app. Based on the data I receive, I then implement a button (for every object). When clicking on that button (of either object), i want to change the visible look of that button (say making button from 'Add' to 'Added') on click.
When I click on the button for object 1 , (it changes from 'Add' to 'Added' ) no problem till now.

But, when I click on the button for object 2, or 3 (or any another object other than 1), the state of 1's button changes back ( from 'Added' to 'Add'). But I want to retain, the state of 1st button as well.

Here's my logic (I am using .ts) :

```
    const sampleData = [
        {id : 1, name : 'Adam'},
        {id : 2, name : 'Stephanie'},
        {id : 3, name : 'Mark'},
        {id : 4, name : 'Catherine'},
        {id : 5, name : 'Kate'},
        {id : 6, name : 'Max'},
        {id : 7, name : 'Jacob'},
        {id : 8, name : 'John'}];
        
        export default function MyComponent () {
        
        const [ status, setStatus ] = useState<any>({
        animate : false,
        name : '' //just to distinguish which button is clicked I added a name prop for 
                  //comparison.
        });
        
    
    // below function is not giving me the dezired output
        const handleAddClick = ( name : string ) => {
        try {
           setStatus ((prevState : any) => ({
            status : {
               ...prevState.status,
               animate : true,
               name
        }})); 
        console.log(status)    
        } catch ( error : any ) {
                console.log ( error );
        }};
    
    // below function is also not giving me the desired output
    const handleAdd_Click = (name : string) => {
    try {
    setStatus ({
    ...status, 
    animate : true,
    name `// no need of using `name : name` as only `name` would suffice here`
    });
    } catch (error : any) {
    console.log(error);
    }
    }
        return (
         <>
        {SampleData.map((data) => (
        <Typography>{data.name} </Typography>
        <Button onClick = {() => handleAddClick(data.name)}
 className = { status.animate && status.name === data.name ? 'changeColor' : ''}> Add </Button>
        ))}
        </>
        )}
```

Infact, every previously clicked button.

I did use 'prevState' to my setState logic for that button, but it is not working.
I tried using 2 different functions as mentioned into the code, but none is retaining the state of the previously clicked button (say, retaining the className of the previously clicked button when we click onto the next button).
Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Could you try to pass your function like onClick={() => handleAddClick(data.name)}

Comment: Yeah I passed my functions the same way, sorry I didn't mentioned into the question

Comment: You only have one `status` for all your buttons, you need to create a component for  Button so that each handle its own `status`

Comment: You have one object in you state, when first button is clicked, name is saved in state. when you click on second button, it overrides the previous name and save the second button name. Also in handleAddClick where you are trying to return new state, that state have different structure as compare to initial one. 
You need a state where you can track which buttons are clicked. You can use id as key and value of type boolean to track button status

Comment: If I have to create an another component , then passing the data.map() as a prop to that component and using useParams() - hook from react would suffice? if yes, could you help me by sending a code sandbox for the same (or you may write it over here )? so that I would be able to keep the track of your point.
It would be a great help. (Please use the sample data as mentioned into the question, if possible) : )

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem right now. First of all, let's investigate your algorithm.

You clicked `Adam`, and your name in the state is `Adam` right now. Also according to your code, if the name equals to `Adam`, your class is changing.

BUT

Since you clicked on another item, you're using your old state since you're holding JUST ONE item in your state.

I suggest that you should hold more than one item (like an array that includes your items). And you should control the classname according to your content of array. Which is like:

If my array in state includes my item, put the class name and "Added" text, otherwise, show default view